# Standardizing code

Tags: jquery, button

I'm not a jQuery savvy therefor the question.
I've got this code for some animated buttons I have in a project of mine:

```
$('.slideshow_thumbOutline').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).animate({'border-color':'#000000'}, 150);
  });

  $('.slideshow_thumbOutline').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).animate({'border-color':'#ffffff'}, 150);
  });

  $('.slideshow_thumbOutline').on('click', function(){
    $(this).animate({'background-color':'#000000'}, 150,
      function(){
        $(this).animate({'background-color':'#ffffff'}, 150);
      }
    );
  });
```

... mouseenter/mouseleave/click events.
I've got about 7 of these.

Question: in order to avoid repeating myself, how can I standardize this?

Thanx.

Pedro

Comment: How the look of the other 6 animations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain your animations:

```
function mouseLeaveAnimation() {
    $(this).animate({'border-color':'#ffffff'}, 150);
}
function mouseEnterAnimation() {
    $(this).animate({'border-color':'#000000'}, 150);
}
function thumbClicked() {
    $(this).animate({'background-color':'#000000'}, 150,
      function(){
        $(this).animate({'background-color':'#ffffff'}, 150);
      }
    );
}

// now add these behaviours to your HTML elements.
$('slideshow_thumbOutline')
  .on('mouseleave', mouseLeaveAnimation)
  .on('mouseenter', mouseEnterAnimation)
  .on('click', thumbClicked)
;
```

Comment: That's the kind of solution I was looking for. Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

You can put all of your events inside one `on` function:

```
$("body").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).animate({'border-color':'#000000'}, 150);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).animate({'border-color':'#ffffff'}, 150);
    },
    click: function() {
        $(this).animate({'background-color':'#000000'}, 150,
            function(){
                $(this).animate({'background-color':'#ffffff'}, 150);
            }
        );
    }
}, ".slideshow_thumbOutline");
```